# Como consultar um dado em um array no Javascript

Tags: javascript

sou totalmente iniciante, antes de mais nada.

Foi proposto um desafio final no sistema Alura em que você tem pedir 6 números para um usuário e sortear 6, depois compara os arrays para ver quanto foram acertados. É um joguinho da Mega Sena.

Eu quero sortear 6 números aleatórios que NÃO se repetem. O que consegui fazer até agora foi:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script> 
 var frase = function(texto) {
  document.write(texto + "<br>");
 }

 var sorteados = [];
 for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {
  var sorteado = parseInt(Math.ceil(Math.random()*60));  
  sorteados.push();
  frase(sorteado);
 }
</script>
```

Gostaria de inserir um `if` antes de cada inserção de número para verificar se ele já existe no array, mas não tenho noção de como fazer. Garanto que já procurei muito, mas nada atende minha dúvida ou é extremamente complicado para um usuário iniciante como eu.

Answer (score 3):

Me solucionaram em outro lugar:

```js
<script> 
 var frase = function(texto) {
  document.write(texto + "<br>");
 }

 var sorteados = [];
 while (sorteados.length < 6) {
  var novo = Math.round(Math.random() * 59) + 1;
  if (sorteados.indexOf(novo) == -1) {
   sorteados.push(novo);
   frase(novo);
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar se um número existe no array, basta utilizar o método `indexOf`

```
if (sorteados.indexOf(sorteado) === -1) {
   // Insere o número pois ele não existe
}
```

`indexOf` vai retornar `-1` sempre que não existir o valor no array

Para não repetir os números, você pode fazer uma verificação recursiva!

Nesse caso ele inserirá os 6 números, mas nunca repetidos

Exemplo:

```
    var frase = function(texto) {
        document.write(texto + "<br>");
    }

       var sorteados = [];


      for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {
          var sorteado = parseInt(Math.ceil(Math.random()*60));     

           // passa o array a ser incrementado e passa "frase" como callback para imprimir o número atual
          uniqueNumber(sorteados);

      }

    function uniqueNumber(array)
    {
    var number = parseInt(Math.ceil(Math.random()*60));

    // Insere se não existir
    if (array.indexOf(number) === -1) {
        array.push(number); 
        frase(sorteado);
    } else {
        console.log('repetiu');
        uniqueNumber(array);
    }

}
```

Para ignorar os números repetidos, deixando com menos números caso haja repetição.

Por exemplo `[1, 2, 3, 1]` se tornar `[1, 2, 3]`, basta remover o `else` da função `uniqueNumber`.

Veja um exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vbxkfn2t/)

Comment: Isso responde a dúvida, porém vale ressaltar que caso um número já exista ele não irá inserir, mas continuar a iteração no loop resultando em um número a menos no final do array.

Comment: Grato pela resposta.

Colei seu código mas os números continuam repetindo.

Comment: Ops! desculpa. Atualizado. Esqueci de tratar da função que escreve o texto! A função `frase` deve estar dentro da verificação se já existe ou não aquele número, dentro de `uniqueNumber`